# SetEnv REMOTE ADDR if x-for-forwarded is present

Tags: apache-2.4

I can translate this in PHP.. but I am curious if it's possible to write this in on .conf file.. background of the setup. We have an ELB behind ec2 on AWS. We found out that REMOTE_ADDR is giving us the ELB ip address and not the client. So we want to fix this. 2 options 1.) in PHP or 2.) If can write in apache..

Can any give me an idea to write the snippet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you stuck with Apache 2.2 or can you install the current (2.4) release?

Comment: IIRC, Apache 2.2 can use `mod_rpaf` for this.

Comment: sorry updated tag we are using 2.4

Answer (score 1):

For Apache 2.4+ you can use [the built in `mod_remoteip` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) to do the substitution automatically, which should already be included with your Linux distribution.

For Apache 2.2 you can use a [mod_remoteip backport](https://github.com/ttkzw/mod_remoteip-httpd22) to do this substitution, or you can use the [third party mod_rpaf module](https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf), which may already be included with your Linux distribution.

Comment: I read documentation.. okay it will change the IP address.. sorry but I'm not that much expose on servers.. but can you site example on how to use..